# Forward simulation with partial simulation relation

Tags: coq

I am trying to prove the following forward simulation statement.

```
Theorem forward_sim : forall a b a1 b1,
  compile a = Some b -> (* H *)
  compile a1 = Some b1 ->
  reduces_to a a1 ->
  reduces_to b b1.
```

The simulation relation `compile` is a partial function.
I'm using a Coq function so I can compute using it.

The proof goes by induction on a. But once I `simpl` the hypothesis labelled `H` above, annoyingly I cannot `rewrite <-` the goal with it because of the option.

I just want to ignore the cases where `compile` is `None` and the simulation relation is not defined.
I know of a few ways to represent partial functions:

- dependent types
- option
- use an inductive predicate instead
- ad hoc default value

but none seem to give me what I want to express without some other downside, like losing the ability to `simpl`. An ad hoc default value seems like it would cause problems later on, like extra hypotheses everywhere.

Any tips?

Comment: I usually go with ad hoc default values + extra hypotheses and it works quite well. You can also bundle the extra hypothesis in with the type, like in MathComp (see eg [ordinal](https://math-comp.github.io/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.fintype.html) or [tuple](https://math-comp.github.io/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.tuple.html))

Comment: Without showing a minimal working example, i.e., an actual piece of code, it's difficult to give any tips. But since you want `compile` to compute, I would leave that one alone, and instead think about `reduces_to`. I take it it's defined inductively? In this case a proof by induction on the derivation of `reduces_to` ought to work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Induction on the derivation did indeed work better, however later on I ended up making compile into an inductive predicate as well, so the problem kind of went away. I guess in future I might have a function version of compile and some kind of equivalence to convert between them...